# Material ui TypeError: palette.theme undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to use the List component of mui, just installed the required dependencies.

error is

```
TypeError: theme.palette is undefined
./node_modules/@mui/material/ListItem/ListItem.js/ListItemRoot<
node_modules/@mui/material/ListItem/ListItem.js:85
```

My component is really simple, it is just returning the List item with a ListItem. The component is being rendered by a Route tag from react-router-dom with the element prop

ProductList.jsx

```js
import List from '@mui/material/List'
import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem'
import { data } from "./data.json"

export const ProductsList = () => {
    return (
        <List>
            <ListItem>
                content
            </ListItem>
        </List>
    )
}
```

Component rendered on the harcoded route "/217/cerveza-script" App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
    Routes,
    Route,
    useLocation
  } from "react-router-dom";
import { AdminHome } from "./admin/AdminHome"
import { NavbarAdmin } from '../components/admin/NavbarAdmin';
import { ClientsView } from "./admin/ClientsView"
import { NewClient } from './admin/NewClient';
import { Profile } from './Profile';
import { Settings } from "./admin/Settings";
import { Employees } from './owner/Employees';
import { OwnerHome } from './owner/OwnerHome';
import { Box } from '@chakra-ui/layout';
import { ProductsList } from '../components/menu/ProductsList';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Box backgroundColor="gray.50" style={{height: "100vh"}}>
            <NavbarAdmin />
            <Routes>
                <Route exact path="/" element={ <AdminHome />}/>
                <Route exact path="/owner" element={ <OwnerHome />}/>
                <Route path="/clientes" element={ <ClientsView />}/>
                <Route path="/nuevousuario" element={ <NewClient />}/>
                <Route path="/perfil" element={ <Profile/> }/>
                <Route path="/ajustes" element={ <Settings /> }/>
                <Route path="/empleados" element={ <Employees /> }/>
                <Route path="/217/cerveza-script" element={ <ProductsList /> }/>
            </Routes>
        </Box>
    )
};

export default App;
```

I am also using ChakraUI for the rest of the ui components (only using mui for the List and tables)

package.json

```json
{
    "name": "client",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@chakra-ui/icons": "^1.1.1",
        "@chakra-ui/react": "^1.7.2",
        "@emotion/react": "^11.6.0",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
        "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
        "@mui/material": "^5.0.6",
        "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.2",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.15.1",
        "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
        "axios": "^0.24.0",
        "framer-motion": "^4.1.17",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.0.2",
        "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
        "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
        "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    }
}
```

edit: Posted wrong package.json

Comment: Seems to be something related with theme, as I'm getting the same error no matter with component I render.

Comment: Is this your full code ! where are you rendering your exported ProductsList component? please provide more details. @PatricioAnastacio

Comment: Is rendered directly on App.js, just updated with App.js code

Comment: First thing first, why are you mixing package versions in the first place? `@mui/material` and `@material-ui/core` are in fact the same library. It is just that one of them is V5 and the other one is V4. Also, you have Charka UI as well. Which framework are you actually using?

Comment: I just copied the installation steps on the mui page. The decision on which framework to use is not on me, we are using chakra for everything but tables and lists, kind of no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `ProductList.js` import `List` and `ListItem` from `@material-ui/core/` instead of `@mui/material/`.

Change this,

```
import List from '@mui/material/List'
import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem'
```

To this,

```
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';    
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
```

Comment: Thanks! It fixed it. Any idea why I have to use @material-ui ? I was almost copy pasting the docs on lists and seems pretty rare that it didn't work

Comment: how do you install MUI, by running `npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled` or `npm install @material-ui/core`  !